# OCaml Signature Functors

Tags: ocaml, functor

I am trying to *extend* a functor in OCaml.
For example, assume the following functor `X`:

```
module type X = functor (A : ModuleA) -> I with type t := A.t
```

I am trying to create a similar functor `Y` that also accepts `A : Module A` but returns an extended version of `I`.
I am trying something like:

```
module type Y = functor (A : ModuleA) ->
  sig
    include X(A)
    val blah : A.t -> int
  end
```

But I get a syntax error on this.
I am trying to extend the resulting signature from `X` with more functions. Is this possible in OCaml? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I guess my question is: why don't functors behave the same way for modules and module types?

The functor `X` above returns a module type (or at least that's how I read that expression). If this expression is allowed, then why does OCaml forbid extending the resulting module type?

Comment: Which syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge this is not possible. You will have to do

```
module type Y = functor (A : ModuleA) ->
  sig
    include I with type t := A.t
    val blah : A.t -> int
  end
```

Hopefully someone else can elaborate why the feature you were trying to use is not implemented. Possibly there is a good reason.

EDIT:

If you already have a module `XX` of type `X` (an instance), you can do

```
module type Y = functor (A : ModuleA) ->
  sig
    include module type of XX(A)
    val blah : A.t -> int
  end
```

Comment: This is not possible because X is not a functor but the signature of a functor. You can't apply it for the same reason that you can't apply the type of a function.

Comment: @PatJ: True, but the analogy breaks down when it comes to usefulness. Functor types are dependend types. Having a way to obtain the output type of a functor application without actually doing the application would be useful.

Comment: I'll have to admit, but anyone who works with functors declares the return type somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @kne. I implemented your first suggestion.
It's annoying to have to maintain the duplicate code in `X` and `Y`, but I can live with that :)